# ILI9341 Micro SD Card fails to mount

Tags: esp32

I have purchased a set of 2.8" LCD screens and they work great with my ESP32-S3 based system. The SD card is not working very well though. We are programming the board with the ESP-IDF extension to the Eclipse IDE and using its built in SD_Test example. The SD card will initialize but its file system always fails to mount. We have tried many steps to get to remedy this.

1. Reformatting the SD card to FAT32
2. Checking the SPI interface with an oscilloscope
3. Writing a new SD card code to manually initialize and mount the SD card
4. Reducing SPI bus clock speed from 20MHz to 40-400kHz
5. Trying both 3.3V and 5V
6. Supplying power directly to the screen separate from the system.
7. Putting stronger pull up resistors on the SPI lines

We are running out of troubleshooting steps and can't figure out what the issue is. Has anyone had luck getting this SD card interface to work with the ESP-IDF software.

Comment: We have no idea what you bought. How does a TFT controller IC relate to SD card?

Comment: Careful: You talk a lot about SD cards, but modern cards are SDHC or SDXC. Those protocols are not entirely compatible - an SDHC reader must support this card type at least. A lot of older µC example code does not.